# Any way to specify process to call on Linux when OOM activates?

Tags: linux, memory, out-of-memory, hook

On my embedded system I'd like to record when the system OOM killer actives, e.g. by setting an env. variable in u-boot.  Is there any way to specify a hook function to call on the OOM event?

Comment: I believe you will be able to achieve this using [System Tap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap)

Comment: Also, isn't there usually a log entry when the OOM killer starts blasting away, or did you turn logging off?

Comment: Logging is still on, but I'd prefer an event based callback.